# Объявить User-Agent в Chrome, Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, chromedriver

Всем привет! Что хочу получить: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что для этого выполняю:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("--user-agent=PIK_SUPPORT");
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

**Как это сделать вручную:**
*В Chrome в консоли разработчика (F12) на вкладке Network нажать три точки в правом верхнем углу -> More tools -> Network conditions, затем в секции User agent: снять галку и в поле ввода вписать PIK_SUPPORT*.

При запуске теста не получаю свой результат, агент в браузере остается по дефолту, подскажите, к тому ли аргументу я вообще обращаюсь и если не к тому, можно ли вообще поменять User Agent в селене.

Comment: [Можно](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18004643/12888024). Попробуйте `"--user-agent=PIK_SUPPORT/1.0"`

Comment: К сожалению, не работает(( , это агент нашего приложения, по нему можно будет скачивать stacktrace, в случае фатальных ошибок PIK_SUPPORT

Comment: Почему бы тогда просто не сделать запрос с помощью `HttpClient`?